# How to implement Branch SDK in my Flutter app

Tags: android, ios, flutter, deep-linking, branch.io

I've been using Branch.io for app deep-linking for a while.

Everything works fine and I'm quite used to its mechanism.

Recently I started to play with Google Flutter to build cross-platform apps.

Would like to know if it's possible to integrate Branch into a Flutter project and how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, Branch does not have a native flutter package yet. We currently support Android, iOS, React Native, Cordova, mParticle, Titanium, Unity and Xamarin. Until we roll out our package for Flutter, you can use our HTTP API: https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/deep-linking-api/
​
We also have integration guidelines on native apps: 
Android: https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/android/#integrate-branch
iOS: https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/ios/#integrate-branch

Hope this helps!

Comment: It would be real nice to have a support since Flutter is gaining so much popularity that even my team migrated away from React-Native. Much better DX, performance and better language (dart).

Comment: @jackie-choi Any ETA on when Branch will make a Flutter SDK? 

The unofficial one crashes my Android app on the first launch unfortunately so can't really use it.

Comment: @Vlad which unofficial one crashes for you? Is it `flutter_branch_sdk` or `flutter-branch-io`?

Answer (score 6):

I've started using [flutter_branch_sdk](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_branch_sdk) and it's working well so far.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the step by step integration using [`flutter_branch_sdk`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_branch_sdk) package here: https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/flutter-sdk-basic-integration

And an example here: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-deep-linking-using-branch-i-o-2e96c0de07fa

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [flutter-branch-io](https://github.com/blackmenthor/flutter-branch-io/) package,
it hasn't been released yet.

Comment: why is their repo archived?